# eqmcc function in R QCA package exiting with error

Tags: r

When I attempt to call eqmcc() against a truthTable object, the result is this error message:

> Error: The outcome's length should be the same as the number of rows in the data.

Here's my script:

```
library(QCA); library (psych); library(readr)
gamson <- read_csv("/path/to/Gamson.csv", col_names = TRUE)
is.na(gamson)
ttACP2 <- truthTable(data=gamson, outcome = "ACP", conditions = "BUR, LOW, DIS, HLP", n.cut=3, incl.cut=0.750, sort.by="incl, n", complete=FALSE, show.cases=TRUE)
ttACP2
csACP2 <- eqmcc(ttACP2, details=TRUE, show.cases=TRUE, row.dom=TRUE, all.sol=FALSE, use.tilde=FALSE)
```

The is.na() function shows that there are no missing values in my data set.  The data set contains 54 rows, of which the first is the column names.  The truth table is generated according to expectations.  But the minimization of the selected causal conditions fails.

I found a chunk of source code that matches the error message on line 90 here:

> https://github.com/cran/QCApro/blob/master/R/pof.R

But I'm not competent enough in programming to understand what conditions lead to the error message being thrown.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your dataset is a tibble instead of a dataframe. After loading the dataset, and before finding the truth table, do this:

```
gamson <- as.data.frame(gamson)
```

It should work after that. (The latest version of the `eqmcc` function is called `minimize` now.